# How do I detect "one scaling level for all displays"?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 introduced this ridiculous <strike>bug</strike> feature where it automatically decides the DPI scaling for the user on a per-screen basis. I am instructing users to turn this feature off, by clicking the checkbox in the Control Panel for "Let me choose one scaling level for all displays". This 1:22 minute video shows where the setting is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE3IUTPy1WA

Anyway, my question is, how can I programmatically determine whether this setting is turned on or off? Is there a Win API call that I can make, or a registry setting that I can query? If this setting is turned off, I want to be able to detect that inside my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Win8DpiScaling`

This key and other related keys are documented at [DPI-related APIs and registry settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528846.aspx) but the relevant text follows:

> The Control Panel\ Appearance and Personalization\Display user
>   interface (UI) includes a checkbox: Let me choose one scaling level
>   for all my displays, which controls whether the system applies a
>   single scale factor to all displays (as in Windows® 8 and earlier
>   versions of Windows), or different scale factors that take into
>   account the pixel density of each display (the Windows 8.1 default).
>
> This checkbox configures the HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Win8DpiScaling
>   registry key in Windows 8.1.

```
Key value : 0   Meaning : Different scale factors for each display: Windows 8.1 default.Content that is moved from one display to another will be the right size, but can be bitmap-scaled.
Key value : 1   Meaning : Same scale factor is applied to all displays: Windows 8 and earlier Windows versions behavior.Content that is moved from one display to another might be the wrong size
```

Comment: Er, shouldn't a program use the api call rather than a registry? That is unless there is no api.

Comment: @David: To my knowledge, there is no API that returns the value selected through the GUI. While you can call [GetScaleFactorForMonitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302060.aspx) and compare the values, there is no API that tells you whether they are all the same due to this specific GUI setting, or because they were individually set to the same value.